# Shopping cart array error - The element at position 0 cannot be found

Tags: coldfusion

I have the following code

```
        <cfparam name="url.productid" default="">
        <cfparam name="url.qty" default="">
        <cfquery name = "getCartItem" datasource="jeb48_shoppingcart">
        <cfparam name="session.cart" default="arrayNew()">
        < cfset session.cart = arrayNew(1) >
        < cfset thisCartItem = arraylen( session.cart )>
        < cfset session.cart[thisCartItem].itemID = url.productid>
        < cfset session.cart[thisCartItem].quantity = url.qty>
        </cfquery>
```

The previous page is sending the following info:

```
shoppingcart.cfm?productid=#getlist.productid#&qty=1&action=add
```

I'm getting "The element at position 0 cannot be found. " error page when loading the shopping cart. I need to be able to store session variables and build a list of all shopping cart items.

***Edit***
Change the following code

```
        <cfparam name="session.cart" default="arrayNew()">
        <cfset arrayAppend( session.cart, structNew() )>
        < cfset session.cart = arrayNew(1) >
```

Now I'm getting "Error Executing Database Query. "

Comment: Why are you using `cfquery` without any query? Better first go through the CF documentation and then start coding. Go thorough https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfquery

Comment: ColdFusion arrays do not start at `0`, they start at `1` (The way it should be). In your code you are creating a new array (`session.cart`), then setting a variables named `thisCartItem` to the length of that array (which after it is created will always be `0`), then you are trying to use the value of `thisCartItem` (which is `0`) as the position in the array (`session.cart`). There is not index `0` in ColdFusion arrays. That, right there, is yoru problem.

Comment: @ScottStroz You are going to get hate mail from Java people.

Comment: I'm with Deepak, what's with this line - ` <cfquery name = "getCartItem" datasource="jeb48_shoppingcart">` - doesn't that throw an error?

Comment: Since your original question about arrays was already answered, you should open a separate question about the query. Be sure to include the full `cfquery` code. (What you posted above is not valid). Also, please include the *complete* error message, not just the error header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create an array of structs that contains your `url.productid` and `url.qty` use the following

```
<cfparam name="session.cart" default="arrayNew()">
<cfset products { 
    itemID: url.productid,
    quantity: url.qty
}>
<cfset arrayAppend(session.cart, products)>
```